# How to get the text from the POST request in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I have a simple form on Angular , where I upload a file and a description.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
upload(files) {
    if (files.length === 0)
      return;

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    var filedesc = this.description;

    for (let file of files) {
      formData.append(file.name, file);
      formData.append("Description", filedesc);
}
const uploadReq = new HttpRequest('POST', `api/upload`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
    });
```

In the controller, I get only the file name.

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public  ActionResult UploadFile()
        {
            try
            {
                var fileContent = Request.Form.Files[0];

                string folderName = "Upload";
                var contenttype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
                string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
                }
                if (fileContent.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (fileContent.ContentType == contenttype)
                    {
                        string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(fileContent.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                        string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);



                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            fileContent.CopyTo(stream);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json("Wrong File Type.");
                    }
```

My question is how to receive description string in this case? Or is it bad that I append file and description in one request?

Comment: why are you appending the same file description with each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said Aman B before, add a parameter and use this code

```
 foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
                {
                    description = key;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a parameter to your action method to receive the description:

```
//If you are expecting a single file description
public  ActionResult UploadFile(string description)
        {
  //Logic..
}


    //If you are expecting multiple file descriptions
    public  ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<string> description)
            {
      //Logic..
    }
```

It is ok to send form data with files in the same request. This is what the `"multipart/form-data"` content-type header is used for.